# Multilingual website in ReactJs without using i18nect

Tags: reactjs

Is there any way to create multilingual website without using i18next and related libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Yes, you can create a multilingual website without using i18n but it is not efficient. Effectively what you need to do in that case is reinvent the wheel; i18n is just a library; that is an already written code for you to use. If you don't want to use i18n you can rewrite that functionality by yourself. There are other libraries but they all follow the same path as i18n and are all used in the same manner.